# border radius ugly rendering on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, image, cordova, font-awesome, css

I'm developing a simple app with Cordova/PhoneGap and using FontAwesome (and border-radius) to display some social media icons. I made the build via `cordova android build` on the CLI.

The social media icons look neat and crispy on an Android 4.4.2.

But on an Android 4.0.3 tablet, as well as on my colleague Android 2.3.6 smartphone, it looks bad, like in [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/885vg7ibl403gqt/social-media-icons.jpg) (from the tablet).

The border radius is awfully rendered, but the FontAwesome icons also look bad.

Why? Should I avoid using FontAwesome and/or border-radius in Cordova/PhoneGap applications for older Android devices? How could I serve better images on these devices?

What I'm doing right now with other images is using media queries:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    #logo-home { width: 32px; height: 32px; background: url('../img/logo-home64x64.png'); background-size: 32px 32px; }
}
```

You can notice I'm actually loading a 64x64px image and setting it's dimensions to 32x32px. Is that a good practice?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Here's a comparison between two PNG screenshots (the one from the link above is a JPEG that might be a bit compressed) from my Android 4.0.3 device (Galaxy Tab GT-P3100):

[image 1](http://res.cloudinary.com/dmxkidzrn/image/upload/v1401113664/icons-1_i7m7ht.png) - these are FontAwesome icons and border-radius

[image 2](http://res.cloudinary.com/dmxkidzrn/image/upload/v1401113664/icons-2_t4pqt4.png) - these are PNG images

The PNG icons are a bit smaller and the icons aren't exactly the same, but you can see a drastic difference between them.

Why the border-radius rendering quality is so poor? Regarding the icons, it's actually only the YouTube FontAwesome icon that looks ugly.

CSS for the FontAwesome icons with border-radius:

```
.social                     { margin: 0 auto; }
.social .item               { margin: 3px; text-align: center; font-size: 24px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; width: 44px; height: 44px; background-color: #68a225; color: #fff; border: solid 1px #fff; border-radius: 22px; }
.social .item:hover         { background-color: #fff; color: #68a225; border: solid 1px #68a225; margin-top: 0;} 
.social .item i             { margin-top: 12px; }
```

Comment: One, that screenshot is horribly compressed, so I really can't tell what is JPG artifacts and what is from the device. Two, while it's possible to use scaling as you do (frankly, most of my apps do, but I worry more about iOS than Android), it's *best* to use icons that are targeted to your device's pixel ratio. For example, if your device's pixel ratio is >1 and <2, you're going to end up with less-than-perfect results no matter what, unless the image is designed for that scaling factor. All that said, if you're using `border-radius`, I wouldn't expect *that* to be affected -- just the image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I linked two screenshots for a comparison, using png now. I understand your point about pixel ratio, but Android devices vary a lot in terms of pixel-ratio, so I guess I'm better off using svg or font icons, right?

Comment: Yes... and no... support for SVG varies widely, and just because you have a vector doesn't guarantee it will be pixel-perfect at a specific size. Font Awesome, for example, are built to be pixel-perfect at a specific size (I forget which) and will look good at other sizes, but not as sharp. Sadly, there's no good way except to rebuild and hint your icons for each size if you want ultimate sharpness. As to those border radii -- well, for Android 2.x, this is par for the course -- there is no workaround except to use pngs. I'm surprised Android 4.0.3 is having a problem, though.

Comment: What code are you using, specifically, for a font awesome icon?

Comment: I get your point - no matter if served as vector or raster, images on a screen end up displayed in pixels, so there's an optimal size for each image for each pixel density variation possible. That might be what's going on with the FontAwesome YouTube icon. The border-radius issue is still a mystery for me though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font Awesome's method called "Stacked Icons":
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/ - scroll down to Stacked Icons

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0n4ou4y3/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fa-stack .fa-circle {
    color: #68a225;
    }
</style>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```